# Vuetify VDatePicker menu bug

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a project (vue2 + vuetify2) with a component v date picker, which attribute active picker = "YEAR" and a list of years from 2000 to 2100, the problem is that sometimes the component opens on the selected year, and sometimes scroll up and the last years are already displayed (2100, 2099, 2098...), how do I fix that always when opening this component shows the current year?

```
<v-menu
      v-model="menu"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      offset-y
      transition="scale-transition"
      min-width="290"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <div v-if="$slots.activator" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
          <slot name="activator"></slot>
        </div>
        <v-card v-else flat width="100%">
          <v-text-field
            :disabled="disabled"
            :outlined="outlined"
            :dense="dense"
            :filled="filled"
            :rules="[...rules]"
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            :value="getFormattedTime(date)"
            :hide-details="hideDetails"
            :label="label"
            placeholder="placeholder"
            :error-messages="errorMessages"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-calendar"
            clearable
            @click:clear="clearDate()"
            readonly
          >
            <template v-slot:append>
              <v-icon class="pr-2">
                mdi-menu-down
              </v-icon>
            </template>
          </v-text-field>
        </v-card>
      </template>
      <v-card width="290">
        <v-card-text class="pa-0">
          <v-date-picker
            v-model="date"
            color="primary"
            no-title
            :disabled="disabled"
            :min="min"
            @click:date="changeData"
            :max="max"
            :active-picker.sync="activePicker"
            first-day-of-week="1"
            :readonly="readonly"
            :value="defaultValue"
          ></v-date-picker>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-menu>
```

```
props: {
    value: {
      required: false,
      type: String
    },
    label: {
      required: false,
      default: "",
      type: String
    },
    min: {
      required: false,
      default: new Date("1970-01-01").toISOString(),
      type: String
    },
    max: {
      required: false,
      default: new Date("2100-01-01").toISOString(),
      type: String
    },
    hideDetails: {
      required: false,
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    disabled: {
      required: false,
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    outlined: {
      required: false,
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    dense: {
      required: false,
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    filled: {
      required: false,
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    errorMessages: {
      required: false,
      default: null,
      type: [String, Number, Array, Boolean]
    },
    rules: {
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
      type: Array
    },
    yearSelect: {
      required: false,
      default: true,
      type: Boolean
    },
    readonly: {
      required: false,
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    }
  },

  data: () => ({
    activePicker: null,
    date: "",
    menu: false,
    defaultValue: null
  }),

  watch: {
    value: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        if (this.value) {
          this.date = this.value;
        } else {
          this.date = "";
          this.defaultValue = new Date();
        }
      }
    },
    menu(val) {
      val && this.$nextTick(() => (this.activePicker = 'YEAR'))
    }
  },

  methods: {
    changeData() {
      this.$emit("input", this.date);
      this.menu = false;
    },
    close() {
      this.date = "";
      this.changeData();
      this.menu = false;
    },
    toggle() {
      this.menu = !this.menu;
    },
    clearDate() {
      this.date = "";
      this.changeData();
    },
    getFormattedTime(date) {
      const newDate = new Date(date);

      if (newDate) {
        return newDate;
      }
    }
  }
```

Reproduction link: [codepen](https://codepen.io/WhyMe7/pen/XWOeOgP?editors=1111)

I tried adding a value attribute with a value of new Date(), but the problem still remains

Comment: When you open the menu and scroll up or down, then close and reopen the menu, it will show the position you scrolled to before instead of going back to the selected date. Is that the issue you are having?

Comment: @MoritzRingler Yes, but it also happens that the menu scrolls up the first time I open it